# How to display a webpage content in my blackberry browserfield after getting an Http response?

Tags: blackberry

Im making an Http request where it needs authentication. After succesffully authenticated im getting a response code as 200. Then, how should i display the webpages from the server on to my customized browser field.

Answer (score 1):

To display a web page on BlackBerry Screen you can check [How to - Invoke the browser](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800440/How_To_-_Invoke_the_browser.html?nodeid=1487366&vernum=0),If you are working on BlackBerry OS 5.0 you can use [Browser field](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Browser_field_1184788_11.jsp) article. Use BrowserField class to display a webpage on your BlackBerry Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple fragment of code that uses BrowserField to display an html page:

```
    BrowserField browser = new BrowserField();

    String browserContent = "<html><style>" + theStyle + "</style>" + theBody + "</html>";

    byte[] contentBytes;        
    try {
        contentBytes = browserContent.getBytes("UTF-8");
        browser.displayContent(contentBytes, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http://mysite.org");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        browser.displayContent(browserContent, "http://mysite.org");
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply..but my question is when i make a successful http connection i will get the response code as 200, it means im establishing a connection with the url i sent..how to display that url content after gettng the 200 response code.I guess we have to open an inputstream to read the data but how to display it as a webpage.

Comment: So, read Pavan Kumar answer that describes browser behaviour.